# Add default system newline in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix, dos

When I append text to a file I would like to add the correct line ending for the file: for Unix: `"\n"` and for Windows `"\r\n"`. However, I could not find an easy way to do this. This was the best I could come up with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Devel::CheckOS ();

my $fn = 'file';
open (my $fh, '<', $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!\n";
my $first_line = <$fh>;
my $len = length $first_line;
my $file_type = "undetermined";
if ($len == 1) {
    $file_type = "Unix" if $first_line eq "\n";
}
if ($len >= 2) {
    if (substr($first_line, $len - 1, 1) eq "\n") {
        if (substr($first_line, $len - 2, 1) eq "\r") {
            $file_type = "DOS";
        } else {
            $file_type = "Unix";
        }
    }
}
close $fh;
if ($file_type eq "undetermined") {
    $file_type = get_system_file_type();
}
print "File type: $file_type.\n";

sub get_system_file_type {
    return Devel::CheckOS::os_is('MicrosoftWindows') ? "DOS" : "Unix"; 
}
```

Is it really necessary to do all these checks? Or are there simpler ways to do this?

Comment: Just for clarification: do you want to change the line endings based on the OS the script is running on, or the line endings the file contains. (the former should happen automatically).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `:crlf` handle, for example with `use open` and `use if`:

```
use if ($^O eq "MSWin32") => open qw(IO :crlf :all);
```

The relevant documentations:

- [PerlIO](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) for the io layers. Note that this page states:

> If the platform is MS-DOS like and normally does CRLF to "\n" translation for text files then the default layers are :
>
> `unix crlf`

So the above code should be redundant, but that's what you're asking for.

- [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for the `$^O` variable.
- [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) for the open pragma.
- [if](https://metacpan.org/pod/if) for conditional loading of modules.

Comment: Doesn't Perl do this automatically for Windows?

Comment: @Casper: I thought so too, but if you want to do it by hand, that's the probably easiest way to do it.

Comment: Ok, right. The PerlIO man page says it adjusts the default layers depending on the OS: http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html#Defaults-and-how-to-override-them

Comment: Ok, I see.. the line endings are already handled automatically by Perl depending on the system it runs on.. That is great.. Then if a I have DOS file on a Unix OS, it will get "corrupted" (get mixed line endings) if I append lines to the file.. If want to avoid this I have to add special code to deal with it..

Comment: So if I understand correctly: The following code will work on both Unix and DOS: `print $fh "Line to be appended\n"` .. (The trailing "\n" will be automatically converted to `"\r\n"` on a DOS OS, is that right?) ( I do not have a windows machine to test this for myself)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Yes, it should. If you have a `\r\n` file on a unix system, you simply can `open my $fh, '>>:crlf', 'yourfilename' or die` and you should be fine.